# tryCatch with a function that uses try internally does not catch the error in any way

Tags: r

I have noticed that tryCatch a function (can be a function coming from a library so can't modify source code) that is already protected with a try does not really catch the error. As a result I end up checking for "try-error" after every uncertain tryCatch. Any comments if there is a workaround I am missing?

Reproducible example, where foo on failure is try-error object instead of -1 or -2 as I would hope for:

```
foo <- tryCatch({
  try(notTheDroidzYouAreLookingFor())
}, warning = function(w) {
  print("zwarning")
  -2
}, error = function(e) {
  print("zerror")
  -1
})
print(foo)
# ending up doing following all the time
if (inherits(foo, "try-error")) {
  print("tryCatching a try and then checking for try-error makes jack a dull boy")
  foo <- -3
}
print(foo)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. If no error is thrown, no error handler will be called. `try` prevents the error from being thrown.

Comment: So, I recommend not using `try` here. If a package contains a function that can return an object of class "try-error", I'm not sure if I would trust the package.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right.  Was thinking maybe it is possible to capture a specific class on the catch or maybe some R-option that makes try escalate to error... but I have searched and could not find anything relevant...

Comment: Well, you could trace `try`: `trace(try, at = 1, tracer = quote(return(eval(expr))))`

Comment: Just FYI you can change any functions code in R, check out `fix`.  Although sometimes you would need to alter underlining C or other code.